# top bar in wordpress without interacting with the rest

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

i've made this JSFiddle where u can see the html and css code in action:

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/x3GbN/)

How can i add this to a wordpress themes header file without interacting with the current header? atm on my theme there is a margin which makes this top bar not 100%. What can i do in order to copy this in to my header and css file i wordpress on top of the rest?

html:

```
<header class="header1">
    <nav class="nav1">
        <div class="container1">
            <a href="#"><img class="logoimage" src="http://95.85.11.40/topnav/css/img/messages.png">    </a>
            <a href="#"><img class="twitterlink" src="http://95.85.11.40/topnav/css/img/twitter_32.png"></a>
            <a href="#"><img class="facebooklink" src="http://95.85.11.40/topnav/css/img/facebook_32.png"></a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">test 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">test 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">test 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">test 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">test 5</a></li>
            </ul>

            <select> 
               <option value="" selected="selected">Select</option> 
               <option value="#">test 1</option>
               <option value="#">test 2</option>
               <option value="#">test 3</option>
               <option value="#">test 4</option>
               <option value="#">test 5</option>
            </select> 
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: With javascript, if you're not willing to edit / alter the current header.php file.

Comment: Do you have a link or something so i can get started

Comment: Not until I understand the question better: you want to add this menu to WP **without** editing the theme's header.php file, is that correct? If so, what file(s) are you working in? Are you creating a plugin?  Or working in the theme?

Comment: Well i can edit, but just want to change as minimum as possible

Comment: So... you do or don't want to edit the header.php file to include this?

Comment: Well i do just that it is as minimum as possible

Comment: You need to make a decision.  You say you don't want it in your header file - maybe you can create an include file that contains this markup, and use `require_once` to include it in your header? Is that minimum enough?

Comment: yep but the main problem is that